# How to get "Log on as a batch" settings for user using c#

Tags: c#

Is there a programattic way to query local security policy settings in C#, i.e. the values in secpol.msc?

I would like to read the "Log on as a batch" setting for some user. What should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I can't really convert this to C# without taking up several pages of code, so I'll just give a C version.)

You need to:

- Open the local LSA policy using `LsaOpenPolicy`.
- Open the user's account using `LsaOpenAccount`.
- Get their access using `LsaGetSystemAccessAccount`.
- Test for `SECURITY_ACCESS_BATCH_LOGON` in the returned value.

The definitions are in ntlsa.h, supplied with the Windows DDK (inc/api).

Sample code (untested):

```
NTSTATUS status;
OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES objectAttributes = { 0 };
LSA_HANDLE policyHandle;
LSA_HANDLE accountHandle;
ULONG systemAccess;

if (NT_SUCCESS(LsaOpenPolicy(NULL, &objectAttributes, POLICY_LOOKUP_NAMES, &policyHandle)))
{
    if (NT_SUCCESS(LsaOpenAccount(policyHandle, SID_OF_THE_USER, ACCOUNT_VIEW, &accountHandle)))
    {
        if (NT_SUCCESS(LsaGetSystemAccessAccount(accountHandle, &systemAccess)))
        {
            if (systemAccess & SECURITY_ACCESS_BATCH_LOGON)
            {
                // Batch logon allowed!
            }
        }

        LsaClose(accountHandle);
    }

    LsaClose(policyHandle);
}
```

Comment: ACCOUNT_VIEW - what type should be here (LsaAccountAccess  ?) ?

Comment: Useful web sites: http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid2FBB7FB32D844E33F4C99984CA21E15E229680A1.aspx?s=rxlevel 

and 

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/266094-lsa-functions